# How many BLE devices can be connected on Ubuntu16.04?

Tags: bluetooth

I'm developing the program to get data from four ble sensors using bluepy and Bluz on Ubuntu16.04. Until now, I successfully connected to three sensors but connection to the 4th sensor failed. Any three sensors of total four sensors can be connect but the 4th sensor can't.

Is there any limitation of connections to ble sensors on Ubuntu?